# Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater for ionic +3.0.0

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, command-line, deployment

[my java version 9.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEBlR.png)

[Gives a version error because it says it is the version below 1.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm5qE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the JDK installed the error exit 1 is usually throwed because of it. 
You can find it on here.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html

Comment: it is solved dude.It is because of JAVA SE 9.When you download all SE6,7,8 it doesnt give a single error.JAVA SE9 is a new thing and it doesnt have a SDK version number yet.Quite buggy for building mobile app